# Why aren't my ellipses in the center?

Tags: swift, core-graphics, transformation, quartz-graphics

I'm trying to have several ellipses centered with different sizes and different rotations around their center but I'm getting this:

[image]

My playground code so far:

```
import UIKit

func radians(x: Int)->CGFloat{
    let pi = M_PI
    return CGFloat(pi * Double(x) / 180.0)
}

let size = CGSize(width: 600, height: 600)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, true, 0.0)

let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor);

let center:CGPoint=CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2)

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

var step=0
while step<12{
var width:CGFloat = 25.0+CGFloat(step)*20.0
var height:CGFloat = 100.0+CGFloat(step)*20.0
CGContextRotateCTM( context, radians( 10 ) ) ;
var circle:CGRect = CGRectMake(center.x-width/2,center.y-height/2,width,height);


CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, circle);

CGContextStrokePath(context);
    step++
}

let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()


UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Comment: `CGContextRotateCTM` rotates around (0, 0), not the center.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5983090/4151918

Comment: @LeoDabus CGRectMake(center.x-width/2,center.y-height/2,width,height); is exactly that, isn't it?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're aiming for. Can you include a sketch of what it should look like?

Answer (score 0):

The expected result was:

[image]

And I found a solution after SEVERAL tries.

```
import UIKit

func radians(x: Int)->CGFloat{
    let pi = M_PI
    return CGFloat(pi * Double(x) / 180.0)
}

let size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, true, 0.0)

let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor);

let center:CGPoint=CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2)

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, center.x, center.y)
var step=0
while step<12{
var width:CGFloat = 30.0+CGFloat(step)*CGFloat(step)
var height:CGFloat = 50.0+CGFloat(step)*CGFloat(2*step)

var circle:CGRect = CGRectMake(-width/2,-height/2,width,height)
    CGContextRotateCTM( context, radians(step))

CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, circle);

CGContextStrokePath(context);
    step++
}

let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Comment: you ended up using the frame I told you X minus half width and Y minus half height `CGRectMake(-width/2,-height/2,width,height)`

Comment: You had also to use CGContextTranslateCTM to move the rotation center to the center of the view. You should post an explanation with your new code.